# How can I ask a follow-up question, that assumes there is a possible positive answer to the first question?

Tags: questions

For example:

> "Is there any way to do *something*? **(in that case/ assuming there is
>   / other)**, how is it done?"

Which is the best or more common way to express that assumption?

Comment: Your ideas are fine and common ways of expressing that. Personally, I’d say either of those or I might go with “If so,” for brevity’s sake.

Comment: What @Tyler said. Idiomatically, *"If so, how? [when? | why? | which? | etc.]"* is a common follow-on after an initial question asking whether or not the sought-for information *does in fact exist, and is known to the other person*.

Comment: If there is any way to do something, how can it be done?
Assuming there is a way to do that, how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the conditional "if so..."

"Is there any way to do something? If so, how is it done?"

The "if so" has the same meaning as "if there is a way..."